# Why HttpContext.Session.SetString Lost value in another Action Method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

My project was configured with ASP.NET Core web API.

I have been configured these settings in the Startup.cs file:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSession(option=>{
                option.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                option.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

Configure:

```
app.UseSession();
```

Note: All these Methods in a same controller.

In Method a :

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("key", "value");
```

In Method b:

```
var session = HttpContext.Session.GetString(mobile);
```

But after run, session variable output is null why?

Answer (score 0):

A session is good for browsing  and view and it's not appropriate for web API because it stateless .

Instead, We should use In memory cache to keep temporary data. Even we can set a expiration time and other properties like priority and ...

best regards